# How do you refresh the contents of a div in jquery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `view` called Forms that I am displaying and it has a `dropdownlist`.  When the `dropdownlist` has a different selection, I have a jquery that gets called as so:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myDropDownList").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Forms/' + $("#myDropDownList option:selected").val(),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                // refresh div
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is My Forms View:

```
    @model myProject.ViewModels.PageView

    @section JavaScript
    {
       <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.myJQuery.js")"></script>
    }

    @Html.DropDownList("myDropDownList", Model.selectList)

    <div id="somediv">
       @Html.Label(Model.ValueThatShouldChange)
    </div>
```

So when the `Forms` action gets called again, I have `ValueThatShouldChange` in my ViewModel that will change and they will be displayed in the `div`.  This is why I want to refresh that div but I am not sure how to do that.

I tried `$('#yourdivID').html(data)` but it load my entire view in the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `load()` function to load just the specific part of the page you need by selecting it using its **id**. E.g.:

```
$("#yourDivId").load("/Home/Forms/ #" + $('#myDropDownList option:selected').val())
```

Depending on the way your webpage is build (you don't provide that info), you can also change your Ajax call by including a parameter to load the content you need. E.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myDropDownList").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Forms/' + $("#myDropDownList option:selected").val(),
            data: { id : $('#myDropDownList option:selected').val() }
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
               $('div#yourDivId').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And in your page you just output the content you need based on the **id** (if it's PHP):

```
<? if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
      if ($_POST['id'] == "somediv") { ?>
         <div id="somediv">Just this content should be loaded</div>
   <? }
   }
   else { ?>
     <!-- your regular html... -->
?  }   ?>
```

Comment: The load just deleted what I had in my div but I the ajax call was ok.  I'm gonna accept this answer because you took the time to explain it and you could not have know what I was doing on the server that was causing me grief.  I was returning a view in my partial controller action when I should've returned a partialview.  Anyways, that in combination with your answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$('#yourdivID').html(data)
```

or

```
$('#yourdivID').text(data)
```

depending what you get back from your call

Comment: that url, will load the entire view again so that will not work because it will put my entire page in the div again

Comment: @Pitfall Why would you then make an Ajax request to the entire page? Why not just retrieve the desired content by using a parameter in the call?

Comment: I guess I'm not really sure how to do that.  I'm a little new to writing jQueries

Comment: @Pittfall I edited my answer below to maybe match your needs (if I understand you well).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myDropDownList").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Forms/' + $("#myDropDownList option:selected").val(),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                  $("div").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**HEY. THIS IS THE SMALLEST, FASTEST ANSWER!  :-)**

What you want to do is use the jQuery shortcut $.load() http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(function() {  // <-- shortcut for $(document).ready
    $("#myDropDownList").on('change', function () { 
        $('#target-div').load('/Home/Forms/' + $("#myDropDownList option:selected").val());
    });
});
```

Where #target-div is just the CSS selector of your target div. Change to suit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just redraw the content of the div you can use

```
$('#yourdivID').change();
```